# Creating a function to return boolean result?

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PDO in my function but I have a problem in the code, I want that the function should return `boolean` result but when I enter wrong email its also giving me true.

What is the problem with my code?

```
function user_exists($email, $conn)
{
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(`UserId`) FROM users WHERE `Email` = :email";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    return ($result == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing your query but not reading the result of it, instead your reading weather or not the query was executed right which in your case is always true.

Try this:

```
function user_exists($email, $conn)
{
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(`UserId`) FROM users WHERE `Email` = :email";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchColumn() > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

**[`fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)** will give you the result of your count column and if execute failed or count is 0 it will give you false.

Comment: yeah sure why not :-)